# Trying to get property 'totalInterestPaid' of non-object when object is present

Tags: php, laravel

I have never come across a issue quite like this. Laravel is saying that I am trying to get a property of a non-object when the variable I am referring to is indeed a object.

```
 $balanceToPush = DB::table('loan_balances')
            ->where('loansID', $loan->id )
            ->first();

        $balanceToPush->totalPaid = number_format($balanceToPush->totalInterestPaid + $balanceToPush->totalTaxPaid + $balanceToPush->totalPrincipalPaid, 2, '.', ',');

        //dd($balanceToPush);

        array_push($loanBalancesArray, $balanceToPush);
```

The above code fails at the first variable in the number formatter `$balanceToPush`. I can get rid of the first two and just have, for example, `$balanceToPush->totalTaxPaid` and it will throw the same error.

However, when I dump the $balanceToPush variable it definitely is a object with the fields I am trying to access:

```
{#1249 ▼
  +"id": 2
  +"loansID": 2
  +"loansBalance": 9000.0
  +"totalInterestPaid": 1670.0
  +"totalPrincipalPaid": 1000.0
  +"totalTaxPaid": 551.1
  +"created_at": "2021-09-16 10:12:27"
  +"updated_at": "2021-09-16 10:12:27"
  +"totalPaid": "3,221.10"
}
```

**What I have tried?**

At this point, I copy and pasted the exact variables from the dd($balanceToPush) and pasted them into the code. Same issue.

I tried to clear the cash by doing php artisan clear:cache, still the same thing.

The most confusing part of this all, was that it was all working fine throughout the day. I then took a break for a few hours came back and then this error popped up.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: It say **non-object** so maybe its an array? Try to get with `$balanceToPush['totalInterestPaid']`, worked?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really Laravel that is complaining, this is PHP itself.

Althrough it can be confusing, it is very very very unlikely PHP is making a mistake, and you can assume that at some point, you are indeed trying to get a property from a non object.

One of the common mistakes is to use `dd` in a loop (don't know if that's the case here, but if it is, then you only "test" the first iteration then the script stops).

Try this, I rearranged your code so it is easier to debug:

```php
dump($loan); //the same output as dd, but without stopping the script

$balanceToPush = DB::table('loan_balances')
            ->where('loansID', $loan->id )
            ->first();

dump($balanceToPush); 


//$balanceToPush->totalPaid = number_format($balanceToPush->totalInterestPaid + $balanceToPush->totalTaxPaid + $balanceToPush->totalPrincipalPaid, 2, '.', ',');


array_push($loanBalancesArray, $balanceToPush);
```

You should get a `null` output at some point. If it works, try again but uncomment the `number_format` part.

If you are still getting the same error without any `null` values in the dumps, can you edit your question with the entire exception trace and a wider portion of your code please?

Comment: Thank you so much. It was exactly that. I did this in a loop and one of the values was returning null because I just realized I recently added a couple of features that allowed user entered data and therefore some fields were empty that were not before and I did not code for that. Thanks again!